# How is \0 incorporated into normal text files in reference to fgets

Tags: c, io, c99, fgets, c89

I was just wondering that when you input text just using a normal application such as textedit (on OSX) would it still harbour the same '\0' character on the end of each string so that when read through `fgets()` if would pick said character up and stop reading?

Because I've created a normal text file, but `fgets()` keeps on stopping at the end of the designated length, instead of when it finds that character, so I have suspicious if it actually exists when I write to a normal text file.

For Example:

```
How Are You
There
```

fgets(str, 15, stdin);
This would end up producing: TherAre You

Comment: The string terminator is _not_ in the file. It's added by `fgets`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, text files don't generally contain any control characters. The termination is a C "feature", i.e. a property of how the C language and environment works with strings. Text files are independent of C. The termination is added (to the in-memory buffer into which the data has been read) by the `fgets()` function.

Answer (score 3):

No, in general, text files do not contain `\0` characters.  `fgets` reads the number of characters requested, or to the end of the line, whichever comes first.  It's `fgets` itself that appends the `\0`. From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

> **`fgets()`** reads in at most one less than *size* characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by *s*. Reading stops after an `EOF` or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If your input file does contain a null byte and you're reading with `fgets()` or equivalent, you have difficulty knowing whether the null in the middle of the string was simply a null in the 'text' file or indicates that the last line of the file did not end with a newline, or that the line was truncated.  Clearly, if you try another read and get more data, it was not a premature EOF.  If the character immediately before the null byte is a newline, then you can assume that the null byte is the end of string marker added by `fgets()`.

Generally speaking, therefore, if the file contains null bytes, it is not a good idea to use `fgets()` to read the file.